# Android: How to convert website.type_XXX to String?

Tags: android

How to convert ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE_HOMEPAGE etc to String? For ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone, there is Phone.getTypeLabel,
but for Website, no such function.

Comment: What would you like the string to be? Something readable? The entire type name with namespace?

Comment: Just a short descriptive string just like "Homepage" (for TYPE_HOMEPAGE), "Blog" (for TYPE_BLOG) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a method yourself for them that will return the String for the current type.